# Comparing timestamp columns in php

Tags: php

I have a table that auto updates using the current timestamp. Let the column name be "updatedTime".. It gives us a value of say:

2013-06-02 17:38:10

Now I want to compare this value with the current time and the difference should be Less than 180 seconds...
Which means that the user last updated within at leat 3 minutes.

I have tried:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOW() - updatedTime < 180 AND visibility = 1 AND linkedInId = :linkedInId');
$statement->bindParam(':linkedInId', $linkedInId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
if(($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)))
```

However this doesn't seems to be working as expected.

What else should I try?

Comment: Just to be sure, are we talking about MySQL or other DBMS? This is relevant because other DBMSs have different date hanlding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOW()` returns datetime, not timestamp, to do math on datetime columns use `interval` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) <  updatedTime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updatedTime) < 180 AND visibility = 1 AND linkedInId = :linkedInId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),updatedTime));
```

Or to be exact:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),updatedTime)) < 180 AND visibility = 1 AND linkedInId = :linkedInId');
        $statement->bindParam(':linkedInId', $linkedInId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->execute();
        if(($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)))
```